# Is there any way I can support JWTSecurityTokenHandler on WIF 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, wif

I wanted to support JWT(Json Web Token)  on my WebAPI application that uses WIF 4.5.

I'm using the [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) nuget package that has a `JWTSecurityTokenHandler` that seems to integrate with older versions of WIF.

The problem is that the handler derives the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler` and not from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler` as the config section expects.

I therefore get an **understandable** exception:

```
Parser Error Message: ID1029: The custom type is not suitable because it does not extend the correct base class.
CustomType: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.0.0.127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
BaseClass: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler'
```

My configuration looks like:

```
<system.identityModel>
        <identityConfiguration>
            <audienceUris>
                <add value="http://localhost:49482/" />
            </audienceUris>
            <securityTokenHandlers>
                <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" />
                <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
                    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
            </securityTokenHandlers>
        </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

How can I support JWT on WIF 4.5? Is there any way I can use this package for doing that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is written against .net standard 1.4, which does not include the `System.IdentityModel` APIs, so the package does not have integration with WIF.

Based on https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/94 if you want to use System.IdentityModel through the WIF configuration, you'll need to go back to version 3.x of the package.

You could of course always write your own `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler` implementation which wrap `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandle`